# Change div background color based on select option

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I need the background color of a div element to change based on the current option selected in a select element (see: https://www.neosileurope.nl/test/)

```
<select name="input_13" id="input_5_13" onchange="gf_apply_rules(5,[0]);" class="large gfield_select" tabindex="1" style="width: 100% !important;">
  <option value="---" selected="selected">---</option>
  <option value="RAL 1000 - Groenbeige">RAL 1000 - Groenbeige</option>
  <option value="RAL 1001 - Beige">RAL 1001 - Beige</option>
  <option value="RAL 1002 - Zandgeel">RAL 1002 - Zandgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1003 - Signaalgeel">RAL 1003 - Signaalgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1004 - Goudgeel">RAL 1004 - Goudgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1005 - Honinggeel">RAL 1005 - Honinggeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1006 - Maisgeel">RAL 1006 - Maisgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1007 - Narcissengeel">RAL 1007 - Narcissengeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1011 - Bruinbeige">RAL 1011 - Bruinbeige</option>
  <option value="RAL 1012 - Citroengeel">RAL 1012 - Citroengeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1013 - Parelwit">RAL 1013 - Parelwit</option>
  <option value="RAL 1014 - Ivoorkleurig">RAL 1014 - Ivoorkleurig</option>
  <option value="RAL 1015 - Licht ivoorkleurig">RAL 1015 - Licht ivoorkleurig</option>
  <option value="RAL 1016 - Zwavelgeel">RAL 1016 - Zwavelgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1017 - Saffraangeel">RAL 1017 - Saffraangeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1018 - Zinkgeel">RAL 1018 - Zinkgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1019 - Grijsbeige">RAL 1019 - Grijsbeige</option>
  <option value="RAL 1020 - Olijfgeel">RAL 1020 - Olijfgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1021 - Koolzaadgeel">RAL 1021 - Koolzaadgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1023 - Verkeersgeel">RAL 1023 - Verkeersgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1024 - Okergeel">RAL 1024 - Okergeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1026 - Briljantgeel">RAL 1026 - Briljantgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1027 - Kerriegeel">RAL 1027 - Kerriegeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1028 - Meloengeel">RAL 1028 - Meloengeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1032 - Bremgeel">RAL 1032 - Bremgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1033 - Dahliageel">RAL 1033 - Dahliageel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1034 - Pastelgeel">RAL 1034 - Pastelgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1035 - Parelmoergrijs">RAL 1035 - Parelmoergrijs</option>
  <option value="RAL 1036 - Parelmoergoud">RAL 1036 - Parelmoergoud</option>
  <option value="RAL 1037 - Zonnegeel">RAL 1037 - Zonnegeel</option>
</select>
<div style="height: 30px; width: 100%; margin-top: 20px; background-color: #CCC58F;"></div>
```

For example:

- Option "RAL 1000 - Groenbeige" needs to change the background color to #CCC58F
- Option "RAL 1001 - Beige" needs to change the background color to #D1BC8A
- Option "RAL 1002 - Zandgeel" needs to change the background color to #D2B773
  etc..

Would anyone know how to implement this in Gravity Forms (Wordpress)? Maybe with a script?

http://jsfiddle.net/tnqznhn2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

The variable `colors` has the alternate value of the select box, starting from the first option, which has `selected="selected"`.

Here we get the index of the option ( starts from `0` ) and match it with the array ( to get it's color ) and apply it to the `div`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("change", ".large.gfield_select", function(){
    var colors = ["#CCC58F","red", "#777", "#000", "gold", "grey", "blue", "green", "white", "yellow", "brown", "black", "silver", "orange", "#CCC58F","red", "#777", "#000", "gold", "grey", "blue", "green", "white", "yellow", "brown", "black", "silver", "orange", "#CCC58F","red", "#777", "#000", "gold", "grey", "blue", "green", "white", "#336699", "#f00"];
    var wth = $(this).find(":selected").index();
    var color = colors[ wth ];
    $(".color-bg").css("background-color", color );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="input_13" id="input_5_13" class="large gfield_select" tabindex="1" style="width: 100% !important;">
  <option value="---" selected="selected">---</option>
  <option value="RAL 1000 - Groenbeige">RAL 1000 - Groenbeige</option>
  <option value="RAL 1001 - Beige">RAL 1001 - Beige</option>
  <option value="RAL 1002 - Zandgeel">RAL 1002 - Zandgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1003 - Signaalgeel">RAL 1003 - Signaalgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1004 - Goudgeel">RAL 1004 - Goudgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1005 - Honinggeel">RAL 1005 - Honinggeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1006 - Maisgeel">RAL 1006 - Maisgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1007 - Narcissengeel">RAL 1007 - Narcissengeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1011 - Bruinbeige">RAL 1011 - Bruinbeige</option>
  <option value="RAL 1012 - Citroengeel">RAL 1012 - Citroengeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1013 - Parelwit">RAL 1013 - Parelwit</option>
  <option value="RAL 1014 - Ivoorkleurig">RAL 1014 - Ivoorkleurig</option>
  <option value="RAL 1015 - Licht ivoorkleurig">RAL 1015 - Licht ivoorkleurig</option>
  <option value="RAL 1016 - Zwavelgeel">RAL 1016 - Zwavelgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1017 - Saffraangeel">RAL 1017 - Saffraangeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1018 - Zinkgeel">RAL 1018 - Zinkgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1019 - Grijsbeige">RAL 1019 - Grijsbeige</option>
  <option value="RAL 1020 - Olijfgeel">RAL 1020 - Olijfgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1021 - Koolzaadgeel">RAL 1021 - Koolzaadgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1023 - Verkeersgeel">RAL 1023 - Verkeersgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1024 - Okergeel">RAL 1024 - Okergeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1026 - Briljantgeel">RAL 1026 - Briljantgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1027 - Kerriegeel">RAL 1027 - Kerriegeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1028 - Meloengeel">RAL 1028 - Meloengeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1032 - Bremgeel">RAL 1032 - Bremgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1033 - Dahliageel">RAL 1033 - Dahliageel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1034 - Pastelgeel">RAL 1034 - Pastelgeel</option>
  <option value="RAL 1035 - Parelmoergrijs">RAL 1035 - Parelmoergrijs</option>
  <option value="RAL 1036 - Parelmoergoud">RAL 1036 - Parelmoergoud</option>
  <option value="RAL 1037 - Zonnegeel">RAL 1037 - Zonnegeel</option>
</select>
<div style="height: 30px; width: 100%; margin-top: 20px; background-color: #CCC58F;" class = "color-bg"></div>
```

Good luck